# What is the easiest way to make globe rotation in android with texture?

Tags: android, animation

I have problem with OpenGL and can't get my sphere done so I'm quitting implementation in OpenGL since it's not the easiest way to be done and what I need is, hopefully, nothing so special. So I would need to make animation of globe rotation with it's texture on it. First what came to my mind was making it with `Drawable` but I would need 288 pictures to get nice 24fps rotation in 12 seconds. It's not problem in pictures, because I guess there is some program to make 24fps out of 12 second rotation, but there would be too many redundancy (which would slow down my app) in pictures, since what I really need is one texture wrapped into sphere object rotating.

How can I get my job done easily and elegantly without struggling with OpenGL and still leaving my app run fast?

Comment: honestly I dont know why you are going away from OpenGL... it might be a little bit complicated to start with but it is so nice and can do what you are asking really easily.  Just thinking about having 288 pictures to get 24fps doesnt sound right at all to me.  Just look at http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/index.html I did this a while back and had a cube spinning with texture working in like a day or two of playing around with it.  I know this wasnt the answer you are looking for but thats why this is just a comment :D

Comment: @chancea :) Well, OpenGL is cool when you're having countable amount of vertices, but with globe it starts to be little bit more tricky :)